# On what basis should I upvote identification requests?

Tags: discussion

#### When should I vote up?

> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is
> especially useful, vote it up!

Whenever I see any question which I saw very useful, then for sure it makes me click on that upvote icon. But whenever it comes to questions related to identification request then it makes me puzzle. There are few questions which got really high upvote and it makes me think that on what basis they get upvote on that question. I thought they did that because they are also seeking the same question or they are interested in knowing the answer.

For example this: [Nostalgia Hit Me - But What Anime Is This That Takes Place In An Alternate World That Is Mostly Deserts?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30067/nostalgia-hit-me-but-what-anime-is-this)

It has only 7 views at that time it got up to 4 upvote which is seriously huge for the identification tag.

So I would like to know that when we have to make an upvote on those question which is based on identification request.

Comment: If it's a detailed, well-formatted post that looks like the poster has done research and really tried to do their best, upvote. If it looks like the poster was lazy and didn't try much to make their question answerable, downvote.

Comment: Also we're phasing out image-only ID requests, so I suppose voting on them should not be necessary, as they are quickly closed with a link to our new policy.

Comment: I never upvote them anymore. I downvote particularly bad ones and ignore the less bad ones.

Comment: I totally agree what Hakase said. But never upvote them is bad. I mean this Anime & Manga site is still developing and if we will not support or encourage others then it will be bad for this site. I raised this question because there are so many questions related to identification tag and many people are involved in this.

Comment: If you want to upvote them, that's your prerogative; however, personal experience and [these statistics](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/2468/7579) suggest that people who ask them don't stick around to contribute to the site, so I don't agree with the premise that it makes any difference to site health whether we upvote them or not. We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Now I understand, if we take those statistics into consideration then we should remove identification tag because since its not contributing anything. Its not like I am totally against with this but we must allow this question to be discussed in chat rooms and there they can find answer.

Comment: @Shashank: They are not banned from the chat rooms, but whether anyone would entertain you is another matter.

Comment: Yeah, I actually downvote a large majority of identification requests and do not upvote any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I tend to break down [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions into several parts and see if they suffice to it.

One of the key points I base my [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) up-votes on would be the scope:

> Can the description and information they give match an XX amount of series, or more likely XXXX amount of series?

Some simple mentions of a time-frame or a specific channel usually does the trick. This combined with a 'not too generic' description usually wins me over. This most of the time wins my up-vote, although some of these questions first require some editing.

The second point I tend to look for is:

> proper English usage.

Nobody is perfect, and I myself am nowhere near perfect English either. But at least a minimal effort can be put in, the rest can always be fixed by an edit by somebody who does know the proper way to phrase it.

The final point I judge the question on is:

> Is this a begging letter?

Some [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) questions tend to be 50+% of begging, feelings of nostalgia, despair, sadness and a puppy somewhere in the world might die if they do not get their answer, preferably yesterday than now.

So a short run-down:

- Did they sufficiently narrow down the scope?
- Did they give an adequate description of the series/characters?
- Has some effort been put in the English usage?
- Is it not a begging/psychiatric letter?

But while I might base it all on this, if **you** are doubting, or not sure whether you should up-vote the question, then we can already say that the question was not especially useful or outstanding to you. And as you quoted yourself:

> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment **that you feel is especially useful**, vote it up!

Comment: +1 for "Some identification-request questions tend to be 50+% of begging, feelings of nostalgia, despair, sadness and a puppy somewhere in the world might die if they do not get their answer, preferably yesterday than now."

Comment: And of course, also for a good set of criteria for judging when to upvote them, if you insist on doing so. I use similar criteria for deciding when to not downvote.